# How can I read a NSDictionary using Frida Javascript APIs?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, frida

This is my index.js

```
const className = 'NSURLConnection'
const methodName = 'sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:'

Interceptor.attach(ObjC.classes[className][`+ ${methodName}`].implementation, {
  onEnter: function (args) {
    const request = new ObjC.Object(args[2])
    console.log('HTTPHeaders', request.allHTTPHeaderFields)
  }
})
```

`request` should be a `NSURLRequest`. Whenever I try to log the HTTP headers, this is what I get:

```
HTTPHeaders function () { return retType.fromNative.call(this, objc_msgSend(this, sel)); }
```

`request.allHTTPHeaderFields` should be a `NSDictionary`. My goal is to save each key/value pair inside a javascript object, like this:

```
obj: {
  key1: value1,
  key2: value2
}
```

How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

For simple key-value dictionaries you can easily convert everything to a Java JSON structure by looping through all keys and their values:

```
const className = 'NSURLConnection'
const methodName = 'sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:'

Interceptor.attach(ObjC.classes[className][`+ ${methodName}`].implementation, {
  onEnter: function (args) {
    const request = new ObjC.Object(args[2])
    let json = convertNsDictionaryToJson(request.allHTTPHeaderFields);
    console.log('HTTPHeaders', JSON.stringify(json));
  }
})


function convertNsDictionaryToJson(nsDict) {
    let jsDict = {};
    let keys = nsDict.allKeys();
    let keyCount = keys.count();
    for (var i = 0; i < keyCount; i++) {
        let key = keys.objectAtIndex_(i);
        let value = new ObjC.Object(nsDict.objectForKey_(key));
        jsDict[key] = String(value); // convert everything to a JavaScript String representation
    }
    return jsDict;
}
```

Note that the code converts every value to it's String representation. Depending on what is stored inside the `NSDictionary` this may be necessary or not. The posted code converts everything to String to make sure no ObjC specific types remain as these types can not be serialized if you plan to serialize the JSON structure to a String and print it or use Frida's `send()` method.